# How do I add a top banner to my SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365-developer

I did every step in [this article](http://www.bfcnetworks.com/blogs/alexpearce/add-a-banner-to-sharepoint-2010/) perfectly and still my banner does not populate to the top of my SharePoint site.

Comment: It is because that article talks about implementing in SP 2010. In 2013 its different.

Comment: check this http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/03/20/a-guide-to-quick-sharepoint-2013-branding-part-2-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 uses different set of style and id's.

You can try below CSS

```
#s4-titlerow {
    background:#F9F9F9 url('/SiteAssets/banner.jpg') repeat-x 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
    min-height:121px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:30px 0 0 310px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Replaced my CSS file with your CSS and same result. My banner and css file is uploaded to the assets lbrary but when I make the changes in designer and save it nothing is displayed in the site.  I wonder if  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/siteassets/NewCSS.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> has to be put somewhere else besides line 36? I still put it between the head and the body but its on line 38. Also did I mention I'm using office 365 and my banner is a .png file so I had to change the .jpg to .png.

Comment: What about <div id="s4-titlerow"
   class="ms-dialogHidden s4-titlerowhidetitle">
Should I put it below this?

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: Great it work! looks like the logo, home and edit links moved to the middle though on top of my banner lol. I'll have to see how to get rid of those.

Comment: Where is the Manage Content and Structure under site settings in 2013 so I can hide the global navigation?